# Extraindo valor json de página

Tags: golang

Boa noite. Estou tentando extrair um valor de um json de uma certa página.
Código de tentativa:

```
package main  

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

type Response struct {
    proxy             string `json:"proxy"`
    ip                string `json:"ip"`
    port              string `json:"port"`
    connectionType    string `json:"connectionType"`
    asn               string `json:"asn"`
    isp               string `json:"isp"`
    resType           string `json:"type"`
    lastChecked       int    `json:"lastChecked"`
    get               bool   `json:"get"`
    post              bool   `json:"post"`
    cookies           bool   `json:"cookies"`
    referer           bool   `json:"referer"`
    userAgent         bool   `json:"userAgent"`
    city              string `json:"city"`
    state             string `json:"state"`
    country           string `json:"country"`
    randomUserAgent   string `json:"randomUserName"`
    requestsRemaining int    `json:"requestsRemaining"`
}

func main()  {
    res, _ := http.Get("http://falcon.proxyrotator.com:51337/?apiKey=&country=BR")
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    var myStoredVariable Response
    json.Unmarshal(body, &myStoredVariable)
    fmt.Printf(myStoredVariable.proxy)
}
```

O código não me retorna nada.

Resposta JSON dá página:

```
{
    "proxy": "170.80.14.253:57624",
    "ip": "170.80.14.253",
    "port": "57624",
    "connectionType": "Residential",
    "asn": "263603",
    "isp": "Duplanet Internet E Informatica Ltda - Me",
    "type": "elite",
    "lastChecked": 1552253479,
    "get": true,
    "post": true,
    "cookies": true,
    "referer": true,
    "userAgent": true,
    "city": "Guaramirim",
    "state": "SC",
    "country": "BR",
    "randomUserAgent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Linux Android 4.1.2 DROID RAZR HD Build\/9.8.1Q-94) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/32.0.1700.99 Mobile Safari\/537.36",
    "requestsRemaining": 15588
}
```

Preciso obter o valor de `proxy`, como posso fazer?
Obrigado.

Comment: Apenas um detalhe: você pode converter JSON para Struct usando o site https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/. Os campos devem ser público/exportáveis, com a inicial maiúscula, afinal você está passando este struct para outra biblioteca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os campos da estrutura devem ser [exportados](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers):

```golang
type Response struct {
    Proxy             string `json:"proxy"`
    IP                string `json:"ip"`
    Port              string `json:"port"`
    ConnectionType    string `json:"connectionType"`
    ASN               string `json:"asn"`
    ISP               string `json:"isp"`
    ResType           string `json:"type"`
    LastChecked       int    `json:"lastChecked"`
    Get               bool   `json:"get"`
    Post              bool   `json:"post"`
    Cookies           bool   `json:"cookies"`
    Referer           bool   `json:"referer"`
    UserAgent         bool   `json:"userAgent"`
    City              string `json:"city"`
    State             string `json:"state"`
    Country           string `json:"country"`
    RandomUserAgent   string `json:"randomUserName"`
    RequestsRemaining int    `json:"requestsRemaining"`
    Error             string `json:"error"`
}
```

Comment: Esta resposta deveria de ser marcada como certa.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui desta forma:

```
request, _ := http.Get("http://falcon.proxyrotator.com:51337/?apiKey=&country=BR")
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
var estrutura map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(data, &estrutura)
fmt.Printf(estrutura["proxy"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.Unmarshal` recebe um buffer (array de bytes) e uma estrutura a qual será populada com os valores desse JSON. Onde está a declaração dessa estrutura?

Você precisa declarar a estrutura e uma variável do mesmo tipo antes de passa-la para o Umarshal.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type Response struct {
    proxy             string `json:"proxy"`
    ip                string `json:"ip"`
    port              string `json:"port"`
    connectionType    string `json:"connectionType"`
    asn               string `json:"asn"`
    isp               string `json:"isp"`
    resType           string `json:"type"`
    lastChecked       int    `json:"lastChecked"`
    get               bool   `json:"get"`
    post              bool   `json:"post"`
    cookies           bool   `json:"cookies"`
    referer           bool   `json:"referer"`
    userAgent         bool   `json:"userAgent"`
    city              string `json:"city"`
    state             string `json:"state"`
    country           string `json:"country"`
    randomUserAgent   string `json:"randomUserName"`
    requestsRemaining int    `json:"requestsRemaining"`
}

func recuperarProxy() string {
    res, _ := http.Get("http://api.com/?country=BR")
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    var myStoredVariable Response
    json.Unmarshal(body, &myStoredVariable)
    return myStoredVariable.proxy
}
```

Esse código obviamente não vai funcionar por *http://api.com/?country=BR* não ser uma URL que retorna o JSON mencionado, mas essa é a ideia.

Comment: Não obtive sucesso com este código, simplesmente não me retorna nada. Atualizarei o código de tentativa com o link que retorna o JSON.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com os erros que aparece:

1. Você precisa definir `myStoredVariable` antes.
2. Utilize `myStoredVariable["proxy"]` em vez de `myStoredVariable['proxy']`.

Como ficaria:

```
url := "http://api.com/?country=BR"
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
defer res.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

myStoredVariable := map[string]interface{}{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &myStoredVariable)
return myStoredVariable["proxy"]
```

Na minha solução utilizei um mapa que a chave é um texto e os valores são de qualquer tipo, o bom é que você escreve menos.

Comment: Tentei desta forma e obtive: ``.\teste.go:44:21: type map[string]interface {} is not an expression``

Comment: Deve ser map[string]interface{}{}, não map[string]interface{}.

Comment: Tentei desta forma: ``myStoredVariable := map[string]interface{}{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &myStoredVariable)
return myStoredVariable["proxy"]`` e me retornou: ``cannot use myStoredVariable["proxy"] (type interface {}) as type string in return argument: need type assertion``

Comment: `myStoredVariable["proxy"]` retorna uma interface{}, que pode ser qualquer coisa, se sua função retorna string, você precisa de algum tratamento antes.